# What links the names to the numbers?

Tags: knowledge

And now for an attempt to remove any possible ambiguity from the question:

Match each of the names **Brandi**, **Cyndi**, **Jimi**, **Patti**, and **Tori**, with a unique number chosen from the list **1964**, **1968**, **1979**, **1991**, and **1994**, in such a way that each name/number pair bears a very similar relationship between the name and associated number.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand why this has been closed. With the addition of the first hint I believe that there is likely to be only one demonstrably correct answer. But I will add a second hint.

Comment: I don't think that continuously adding hints will help, not to mention the way it feels like it changes the original question. I would suggest asking a new, more refined version.

Comment: [Here's a relevant meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/re-asking-a-question-when-an-unintended-answer-is-given/6983#6983)

Answer (score 6):

One thing that springs to mind is that these names are all...

> ...**'alternative alternative' names** used by US singer-songwriters:
>
>  ["**Patti**" Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patti_Smith) was born **Patricia** Lee Smith. Patricia is more commonly shortened to 'Pat', 'Patty' with a 'y', 'Trish', 'Tricia' or one of many other variants...
>
>  ["**Jimi**" Hendrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimi_Hendrix) was born Johnny Allen Hendrix and later rechristened **James** Marshall Hendrix. James is more commonly shortened to 'Jim' or 'Jimmy'. Hendrix chose the irregular spelling of his name after a recommendation by his manager, Chas Chandler.
>
>  ["**Cyndi**" Lauper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyndi_Lauper) was born **Cynthia** Ann Stephanie Lauper Thornton. Cynthia is more commonly shorted to 'Cindy', with the vowels the other way around. Lauper chose the irregular spelling of her name on the recommendation of a friend.
>
>  ["**Tori**" Amos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tori_Amos) was born Myra Ellen Amos. While it might seem that 'Tori' would be a shortening of 'Victoria' (which is more usually shortened to 'Vic', 'Vicky', 'Vikki' and the like...) her choice of name reportedly stems from an alternative spelling of '**Torrey**' after a friend's boyfriend once told her she looked a [Torrey pine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrey_pine) tree...
>
>  <sup>*Source for all origin claims: linked Wikipedia pages*</sup>

Comment: (Note there's [another famous alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patti_LaBelle) for Patti - I just chose one, so as not to crowd the answer.)

Comment: Nice, but not quite - maybe wait for a clue.

Comment: With the updated question, you are moving in the right direction wrt who they are - just need to work out how they relate to the numbers

Answer (score 1):

As @Stiv points out these names are

> all first names of famous American musicians. **Patti** Smith. **Jimi** Hendrix. **Cyndi** Lauper and **Tori** Amos.

Now, if we look at

> their last names.. they seem to be all related to Greek deities. *Smith* - Hephaestus. *Hendrix* (meaning ruler of home) - Hestia. *Lauper* (meaning running) - Atalanta. And lastly *Amos* (meaning love) - Eros.

Comment: Nice, but not quite - maybe wait for a clue.

Comment: Yes those are the names of famous US musicians - just need to work out how they relate to the numbers

Answer (score -2):

> Each name: 1. ends with "i", 2. starts with a consonant, 3. has a vowel as a second character, 4. is either 4 or 5 characters long, 5. is two syllables long. If a name is 4 characters long, it's build with [consonant, vowel, consonant, vowel]. If a name is 5 characters long, it's build with [consonant, vowel, consonant, consonant, vowel].

Comment: I feel like the question is probably looking for something more special/distinctive than this.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for.